# How to establish one-to-one relation through IDs between doctrine entities

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, one-to-one

I was hoping this be a straight forward process but it seems Doctrine doesn't really like the idea of linking entities through their IDs.

All I intended to do was normalising a table by shipping some fields from it to a new table and instead of adding a new reference field to the original table to hold the ID of the new corresponding record in the, make sure the new record in the child table will have identical ID to its parent row.

Here is an example of what I have:

A **User** entity, with annotated field `$user` to reference column ID in the  **UserDetail** entity to itself's ID

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci", "charset"="utf8", "engine"="InnoDB"})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends Entity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id

     /**
      * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserDetail", cascade={"persist"})
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
      */
     private $userDetail;

     ...
}
```

and here is the **UserDetail** with its ID's @GeneratedValue removed

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_detail", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci", "charset"="utf8", "engine"="InnoDB"})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserDetail extends Entity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

At this point what my expectation was to be able to do something like:

```
$user = new User();
$userDetail = new UserDetail();

$user->setUserDetail($userDetail)

$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

And get two records persisted to the **user** and **user_detail** tables with *identical* IDs, but the reality is, not having any strategy defined for the UserDetail's identifier, doctrine will complaint about the missing ID, `Entity of type UserDetail is missing an assigned ID for field  'id'.`

Of course it is possible to do the job manually and in more than one call

```
$user = new User();
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();

$userDetail = new UserDetail();
$userDetail->setId($user->getId)    
$user->setUserDetail($userDetail)

$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

But I'm still hoping there is a correct configuration (annotation) that can help me to avoid such extra steps and leave handling of a one-to-one relationship through the entity's IDs to Doctrine.

Comment: Life is too short to worry about such things.  Define UserDetail::id as your basic autoinc primary key then add a user_id column to use as a reference to the user.  And I know.  You want to keep them in sync and not have the extra database column but does it really matter?  When using Doctrine think objects not databases and life will be good.

Comment: @Cerad lol, couldn't be agree more, but unfortunately in this application our team(company) is not in charge of DB, and including the additional column is out of question as there are other consumers (Java based) which can handle such scenarios more easily

Comment: I have seen this question asked a few time but never seen an out of the box solution.  Should be able to implement your own custom id generator.  Have not found any good up to date tutorials on this but you could start here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/GxXAO3-g4vo

Comment: Thanks @Cerad, same here, will have a look at the link and leave an answer if can come up with one

Answer (score 2):

This is untested but I think the following might work, according to the docs (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html):

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Table(name="user_detail", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci", "charset"="utf8", "engine"="InnoDB"})
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class UserDetail extends Entity
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
         * @ORM\Id
         */
        private $user;

    ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Will l I will give it a try and let you know if it works

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, it actually leads to a infinite loop, `function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting!||{"file":"Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php","line":187`

Comment: Sorry Ali, I have tweaked the code in my answer - I meant it to be a proper association to the User entity, but forgot to change the property name.

Comment: No worries, obviously the variable name wont affect the result

Answer (score 0):

I was successful in creating a one-to-one relationship where the primary key is also a foreign key. See below:

The Car Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="cars")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CarRepository") 
 */
class Car
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CarConfiguration", mappedBy="car")
     */
    private ?CarConfiguration $carConfiguration = null;
    
    public function getCarConfiguration(): ?CarConfiguration
    {
        return $this->carConfiguration;
    }

    public function setCarConfiguration(CarConfiguration $carConfiguration): void
    {
        $this->carConfiguration = $carConfiguration;
    }
}
```

The Car Configuration entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="car_configurations")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class CarConfiguration
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="car_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Car", inversedBy="carConfiguration", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private Car $car;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="has_radio", type="boolean")
     */
    private bool $hasRadio;

    public function __construct(Car $car, bool $hasRadio = false)
    {
        $this->car = $car;
        $this->hasRadio = $hasRadio;
    }

    public function getCar(): Car
    {
        return $this->car;
    }

    public function hasRadio(): bool
    {
        return $this->hasRadio;
    }

    public function setHasRadio(bool $hasRadio): void
    {
        $this->hasRadio = $hasRadio;
    }
}
```

The Car repository:

```
class CarRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function persist(Car $car): void
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
        $entityManager->persist($car);
    }

    public function flush(): void
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
        $entityManager->flush();
    }   
}
```

The client code:

```
class AwesomeCommand extends Command
{
    private CarRepository $carRepository;
    
    public function __construct(CarRepository $carRepository) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->carRepository = $carRepository;
    }
    
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): void
    {
        $car = $this->carRepository->find(1234);

        $carConfiguration = new CarConfiguration($car, true);
        $car->setCarConfiguration($carConfiguration);

        $this->carRepository->persist($car);
        $this->carRepository->flush();
    }
}
```

Link:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity